# Optimization of a "multinomial"(?) function

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Consider the following maximization problem:

$$\max_{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n}{f(\mathbf{x})=\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha_i}}$$

subject to

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = c; \ 0\leq a_i \leq x_i \leq b_i \ \forall i \in 1,\dots, n$$

I'm not sure the right term for $f$ is multinomial: I guess that would be the correct nomenclature of all $\alpha_i$ were integer, but that's not necessarily the case. Anyway, I'd like to solve this optimization problem. My first idea was to take the log of $f$, in order to deal with a linear objective function. However, that would mess up with the first constraint  (the others constraints would be fine). So what could be the best approach? Is there some specific algorithm I could use?

Comment: You might note that (if all $a_i > 0$) maximizing $f(x)$ is equivalent to maximizing $\log f(x) = \sum_i \alpha_i \log(x_i)$.  If all $\alpha_i > 0$ that is a concave function.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I noticed that too (and I do have to check if all $\alpha_i$ are positive: I'll let you know). But what about the first constraint? After taking logs, it wouldn't be linear anymore, so I couldn't use linear programming.  Right?

Comment: @DeltaIV Linear programming means both objective function and constraints are linear.  In your original case, the objective is not linear.

Comment: It's not linear programming, but (if the $\alpha_i$ are positive) it is convex programming, which these days is almost as good.

Comment: For example, in Maple the Optimization package should be able to handle it if $n$ is not too huge.

Comment: @RobertIsrael $n$ is "small" (it can vary, but let's say 10). I don't have access to Maple, but I have access to R (and if push comes to shove, I might get access to Matlab and Python). Can you tell me the name of a suitable optimization algorithm for convex optimization? This way I'll check if it's available in the languages I can use.

Comment: @Guangliang of course my original objective is not linear: that's why I wanted to take logs, in order to make it linear. Taking logs makes the objective linear, and doesn't alter linearity of the inequality constraints. However, unfortunately it does transform the equality constraint from a linear to a nonlinear one.

Comment: @RobertIsrael by the way, how can you prove that $f$ is convex if $\alpha_i>0 \ \forall i $? I can prove that its Hessian has all positive elements, but this is not enough to say that a matrix is positive definite (e.g., [[1 2]; [2 1]]).

Comment: A sum of concave functions is concave.  $\alpha_i \log(x_i)$ is concave.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks. I knew about the sum property for functions $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$: if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are concave, then $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is concave too. So it holds also for functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, right? PS Happy Easter!